# Finding solution basis of $y^{(4)}-2y'''+5y''-8y'+4y=0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Find a real-valued solution basis of $$y^{(4)}-2y'''+5y''-8y'+4y=0.$$

The corresponding characteristic equation is $$x^4-2x^3+5x^2-8x+4=0$$ $$\iff(x-1)^2(x^2+4)=0$$ which has the zeros $1, 2i, -2i$. How do I proceed from here? Please share a hint with me.

Thank you.

Comment: If you want to avoid having to guess a solution, another approach is to take the Laplace transform, solve for $X(s)$, and inverse-transform. It's more laborious, but it removes the guesswork and incorporates the data for the initial conditions at $x=0$ as well. (Guessing is easier here, but it's good to have alternatives.)

Comment: Thank you. I have never heard of the Laplace transform. Can you please tell me where I can learn about it?

Comment: Pretty much any book on ordinary differential equations will talk about them. You can also find it on Wikipedia, and there's bound to be a lot of stuff about it online (i.e. google is your friend.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: the multiplicity of the root $x=1$ is $2$; this means that the functions

$$y_i(x)=x^i\exp(1\cdot x)$$

with $i=0,1$ are solutions of the ODE in the OP.

Comment: Thank you sir, so the basis I get is $\{e^x, xe^x, cos(2x), sin(2x)\}$. Random question, but could you (or anyone else) recommend an elementary book on the topic of differential equations?

Comment: You are welcome & right: for ODEs have a look at http://books.google.ch/books/about/Ordinary_Differential_Equations.html?id=JUoyqlW7PZgC&redir_esc=y

Comment: The phrases "elementary" and "differential equations" do not seem to go together! But a top-ranked book on amazon.com is “Ordinary Differential Equations” by Morris Tenenbaum and Harry Pollard, rated 4.7 stars out of 5. I haven't bought it yet but it is high on my wish list.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: zeros of the form $a\pm ib$ correspond to $e^{ax} \cos bx$ and $e^{ax} \sin bx$